# Как убрать мерцание printf()

Tags: c, printf

Написал консольное подобие сапера на Си, но если взять поле побольше, при условии, что оно выводится через printf(), появляется мерцание снизу. Выводится поле таким образом:

```
void printField(struct Cell **a,int N,int M)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < M+2; i++)
    {
        printf("_");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("|");
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {

            char cell = (a[i][j].isCursor == 1)?'X':((a[i][j].isFlag == 1)?'F':
                ((a[i][j].isOpened == 0)?'#':
                    ((a[i][j].minesAround == 0)?' ':
                        (a[i][j].minesAround+48))));
            printf("%c",cell);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < M+2; i++)
    {
        printf("_");
    }
    printf("\nMines left: %d.  Mines total: %d\n",minesLeft,mines);
    printf("Move with - W S A D\n"
           "Open with - ENTER\n"
           "Flag with - F\n");
}
```

Если стандартных способов вывести поле быстро нет, может кто нибудь посоветует в комментах фреймворк какой.
Полный код на https://github.com/mcstarioni/C_games/blob/master/Sapper.c

Comment: А вы попробуйте, к чему вопрос?

Comment: Ну это догадка, я попробую конечно, но вдруг кто-то наверняка знает как это исправить. Или фреймфорк посоветует какой

Comment: Я попробовал, ничего не изменилось, printf все также медленно печатает

Comment: `ncurses`, `S-Lang` и ещё кучка всяких терминальных библиотек, начиная даже с простых кодов терминала.

Comment: @mcstarioni: А какая у вас платформа? Windows или Linux? Кроссплатформенного решения может и не быть.

Answer (score 1):

> фреймворк какой

Есть библиотека, которая специально предназначена для таких целей:

```
man ncurses
ncurses(3NCURSES)                                                          ncurses(3NCURSES)

NAME
       ncurses - CRT screen handling and optimization package

SYNOPSIS
       #include <curses.h>

DESCRIPTION
       The  ncurses library routines give the user a terminal-independent method of updating
       character screens with reasonable optimization.  This implementation is “new  curses”
       (ncurses)  and  is the approved replacement for 4.4BSD classic curses, which has been
       discontinued.  This describes ncurses version 6.0 (patch 20160213).
```